# Injecting dependency from a Class Library project to Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvm, prism, class-library

I have got a brand new Xamarin Form project that requires access to an existing class in a class library project (net standards 2.1).

I would like Xamarin forms to use ClientQueries class from the other project.

*ClientQueries* has got a *HttpClientFactory* property using dependency injection and several methods to call an API and it looks something like this:

```
public class ClientQueries
{
    private readonly ClientFactory _ClientFactory;

    public TSClientQueries(ClientFactory ClientFactory)
    {
        _ClientFactory = ClientFactory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(ClientFactory));

    }

    public async Task<Result<Token>> GetToken(CancellationToken cancellationToken, string username, string password)
    {
        var client = _ClientFactory.Create();
        var response = await client.GetToken(cancellationToken, username, password).ConfigureAwait(true);    
        return response;
    }
```

}

I follow this sample which explains we can make use of Microsoft.Extensions for HttpClientFactory and adding singleton services. This is the link: [ASP.NET Core's Dependency Injection into Xamarin Apps with HostBuilder](https://montemagno.com/add-asp-net-cores-dependency-injection-into-xamarin-apps-with-hostbuilder/)

I tried this StartUp class in Xamarin Forms project which is similar to the asp.net core project which uses the same Class Library with ClientQueries:

```
public class Startup
{
    public static IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; set; }

    public static void Init()
    {
        var a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        using var stream = a.GetManifestResourceStream("App1.appsettings.json");

        var host = new HostBuilder()
           .ConfigureHostConfiguration(c =>
           {
               c.AddCommandLine(new string[] { $"ContentRoot={FileSystem.AppDataDirectory}" });
               c.AddJsonStream(stream);
           })
           .ConfigureServices((c, x) => ConfigureServices(c, x))
           .ConfigureLogging(l => l.AddConsole(o =>
           {
               //o.DisableColors = true;                   
           }))
           .Build();

        ServiceProvider = host.Services;
    }

    static void ConfigureServices(HostBuilderContext ctx, IServiceCollection services)
    {
        #region "api service"  
       
        services.AddSingleton<ClientQueries>();

        services.AddHttpClient<Client>("HttpClient",
            x => { x.BaseAddress = new Uri(ctx.Configuration["APIConfiguration:BaseAddress"]); }
            ).AddPolicyHandler(GetRetryPolicy());

        services.AddSingleton<ClientFactory>();

        #endregion

    }
```

Is it possible to inject ClientQueries in ViewModels like the way I used to do it in asp.net core controllers?

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly ClientQueries _ClientQueries;

    public AccountController(ClientQueries ClientQueries)
    {
        _tsClientQueries = tsClientQueries;
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
      
        var t = await _ClientQueries.GetToken(CancellationToken.None, model.UserName, model.Password);
     [coded abbreviated for simplicity]
```

Or Has Prism got anything functionality which will allow me to use depedency injection for HttpClientFactory in ClientQueries and Use ClienQueries as a singleton in ViewModels in Xamarin?

I tried DependencyServices and I did not get it right.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You register the types with the `IContainerRegistry` and they are injected when the view models are resolved.

Comment: @Haukinger The problem is ClientQueries requires ClientFactory to work. Do I need to include addHttpClient using IContainerRegistry  and the class library can resolve the reference? It was null before when I added on a startup class in xamarin

Comment: Like the view model requires the `ClientQueries`? You have to register _all_ dependencies with the container.

Comment: yes some viewmodels will use clientqueries to call the api and get info. ClientQueries is in a class library which uses httpclientfactory and netstandards. I will follow your suggestion and remove the configureservices and see if it can make it work.
 
The main challenge for me was to use ClientQueries from the other project and that will be able to use dependency injection to resolve httpclientfactory injected from Xamarin. 

I will try IContainerRegistry with ClientFactory and ClientQueries. Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't matter in which assembly a type is defined, as long as it's visible (i.e. `public` or `internal` with `InternalsVisibleTo` for other assemblies or anything in the main assembly) in the `RegisterTypes` method and registered there. Note, that you can split the app into modules where each has it's own registration method (but that is only really sensible if you plan to version and deploy those modules independently).

Comment: Thanks. I understand that. I am encountering a new challenge. I created a new question for this though. By any chance do you know how to register HttpClientFactory for this to work?